# How to customise UITabBar text label?

Tags: ios5, fonts, uitabbar, uiappearance

does anybody know how to use the Appearance proxy object

```
[[UITabBar appearance] set....];
```

to customise the color,font and shadow for the selected/unselected label of an UITabBar?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By accessing the **tab-bar** item object of the `UITabBar` for each `UIViewController`

This only works for iOS5.0 or later.

```
if ([self.tabBarItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes:)]) {
    NSLog(@"*** Support method(iOS 5): setTitleTextAttributes:");
    [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                                [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                nil]];
}
```

Below 5 https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBar